# Mysql foreign key

Tags: mysql

Есть несколько таблиц: user admin client. Здесь указываются роли и создаются отдельные аккаунты для них.

В таблице telegram_id - я указываю Id чата и привязку к столбцам user_id client_id admin_id, изначально, каждое из этих полей может быть пустым. Только после регистрации оно будет изменяться с null на связь с данными.

При использовании команды
`` UPDATE `jobs`.`telegram_id` SET `client_id` = '2' WHERE (`id` = '******'); ``

Падает ошибка:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jobs`.`telegram_id`, CONSTRAINT `telegram_id_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `jobs`.`telegram_id` SET `client_id` = '2' WHERE (`id` = '******');
```

Как решить эту ошибку? Нет возможности изменять связи?

Comment: Для создания внешнего ключа, ячейки должны быть одинаковые. Т.е. одинаковый тип таблиц, одинаковый тип ячейки, одинаковые атрибуты ячейки и т.д. Чаще всего (у меня) встречается, что разный тип ячейки или не указан атрибут `unsigned`

Comment: 1. А клиент с id 2 уже существует? 2. Почему `'2'`, а не `2`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, существует, пытался сделать запрос через Node js, не получилось, решил сделать запрос через UI WorkBench так же -. Запрос и ошибка скопированы с диалогового окна WorkBench.

Comment: @Knyaz71, тип таблиц? Они могут быть разные? Типы данных ячеек совпадают. Могу прислать все запросы по созданию таблиц

Comment: `Да, существует` - а mysql так не думает. И спорить с этим довольно-таки бесполезно. Потому приведите минимальный воспроизводимых пример.

Comment: @Мелкий и правда, нашел ошибку. Причина была довольно проста, обращался к не той таблице в коде. А через UI ошибка возникла из-за отсутствия элемента за этим ключом.